# table columns moved after deleting images (use Datatables with laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I am trying to use data table in Laravel 7 with multiple images facility. When I delete all images for a product, it deletes them. but when I go back to data table, all columns move to one column left. I am attaching an image. I am not sure which part of code I need to provide here. for now I am just giving the controller part.

**controller**

```
public function destroy_allimages($id)
    {
        $car = Car::find($id);
        if (!is_null($car)) {
            foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image) {
                unlink($image->image_location);
            }
            $car->join_caralbum()->delete();
        }
        return back()->with('success', 'Car Deleted Successfully');
    }
```

**blade**

```
@foreach ($cars as $car) 
                <tr>   
                    @php $i=1; @endphp
                 @foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image)
                    @if ($i>0) 
                 <td><img src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" style ="height:90px; width:120px;"></td>   
                    @endif
                  @php $i--; @endphp
                   
                 @endforeach
                
                    <td>{{ $car->visible }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->carreg }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->make }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->model }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->enginesize }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->gearbox }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->fueltype }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->noofdoors }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $car->cartype }}</td> 
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('car_show/'.$car->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-info fa-xs"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('car_edit/'.$car->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-xs"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url('car_destroy/'.$car->id) }}"
                            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete all images for this car?')"
                            ><i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

**js for data table**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () 
    {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "dom": "fliprtip",
        "pagingType":"full_numbers",
            
        lengthMenu: [[5,10,15,20,-1],[5,10,15,20,"All"]]
                        });
    });
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMfEn.jpg)

Comment: share your JS and Blade to be able to help

Comment: I have added the blade and js code now.

Answer (score 0):

this happened because of this piece of code :

```
@php $i=1; @endphp
@foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image)
@if ($i>0) 
    <td><img src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" style ="height:90px width:120px;"></td>   
@endif
@php $i--; @endphp
@endforeach
```

i don't know why you use `$i` variable but you can fix your issue simply by replace with some thing like:

```
@php $i=1; @endphp
@foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image)

<td>

@if ($i>0) 
<img src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" style ="height:90px; width:120px;">
@endif

</td>   

@php $i--; @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am using the $i variable to show only the fist image of the array on the data table. however, i will try your suggestion and get back to you with the result. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@Ibrahim Ezzat yes you are right. thanks a lot. I have edited my code and it works now. this is what I have done

**blade**

```
<td> 
   @php $i=1; @endphp
   @foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image) 
      @if ($i>0) 
      <img src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" style ="height:90px; width:120px;">
      @endif     
   @php $i--; @endphp 
   @endforeach
</td>
```